# Has a wand ever been used as a physical weapon?

Tags: harry-potter

The question occurred to me while watching the episode *Dreams in the Witch House* of *Guillermo del Toro's Cabinet of Curiosities* (2022) in which the witch Keziah Mason threatens Walter Gilman (Rupert Grint AKA Ron Weasley) with a wand in his eye.

It is also worth mentioning Professor Gilderoy and Professor Severus Snape pose in the Spanish and French fencing stances in the film *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* (2002).

The foregoing makes me question if a wand has ever been used as a physical weapon in the Harry Potter universe, in addition to its magical qualities.

[image: Still image from Dreams in the Witch House of Guillermo del Toro's Cabinet of Curiosities (2022)]

Comment: A few years ago, I was under the impression the world of magic wands drastically changed with the influence of Harry Potter. Back then, I would imagine Disney's Merlin casting a spell by delicately waving it like a conductor's baton. But now, I can't help but imagine Daniel Radcliffe pointing a pointy stick menacingly.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Harry (accidentally) stabs a troll with his wand in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*.

> Harry then did something that was both very brave and very stupid: he
> took a great running jump and managed to fasten his arms around the
> troll’s neck from behind. The troll couldn’t feel Harry hanging there,
> but **even a troll will notice if you stick a long bit of wood up its
> nose, and Harry’s wand had still been in his hand when he’d jumped –
> it had gone straight up one of the troll’s nostrils.**
>
> Howling with pain, the troll twisted and flailed its club, with Harry
> clinging on for dear life; any second, the troll was going to rip him
> off or catch him a terrible blow with the club.

He pokes Lockhart with it in *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*.

> White-faced and wandless, Lockhart approached the opening.
> ‘Boys,’ he said, his voice feeble, ‘boys, what good will it do?’
> **Harry jabbed him in the back with his wand.** Lockhart slid his legs into the pipe.

Neville pokes a Death Eater (Walden MacNair) in the eye with a wand in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*.

> Neville had come lunging out of nowhere; **unable to articulate a spell,
> he had jabbed Hermione’s wand hard into the eyehole of the Death
> Eater’s mask.** The man relinquished Harry at once with a howl of pain.
> Harry whirled around to face him and gasped

---

Purely as an aside, (the actress portraying) Bellatrix Lestrange managed to stab (the actor portraying) Neville Longbottom in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

> *"By mistake, I poked him in his ear,"* [Helena Bonham Carter] *explained.*
>
> *"I thought I could brandish the wand like a sort of Q-tip, and clean
> out his ear. Sort of torture it. But unfortunately* [Matthew Lewis] *moved toward the wand as I was prodding it. And it actually perforated his eardrum.
> Isn’t that horrific? I damaged him! He’s such a nice young man, he
> didn’t admit to me that he actually had some internal bleeding about
> three days later."*
>
> *She explained that there was no permanent damage, but there was "pain
> and blood".*
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter: The actor who seriously injured Neville Longbottom star Matthew Lewis on set in torture scene](https://www.mylondon.news/whats-on/film-news/harry-potter-injury-bellatrix-neville-22053032)</sup></sub>

Comment: That's interesting, I thought he actually became deaf from one ear because of the eardrum being pierced.

Comment: @Clockwork - **Q:** *I understand there was an incident between yourself, Helena Bonham Carter and a wand? **ML:** We were doing a scene in the Ministry of Magic where she’s holding [me] and Helena plays the character really well, being sadistic and twisted about it. She was moving the wand about on my head, just teasing me and I’m pulling away in fear. But then she put it straight into my ear and the doctor had to have a look at it and I was deaf for two days in that ear which was pretty weird. She was very apologetic and I can hear fine now! -* https://tinyurl.com/bp54xktn